# Can a function throw derived class exception when its exception specification has base type?

Tags: c++

i have the following code.

```
class Base{};
class Derived: public Base{};

class Test
{
public:
    void fun() throw(Base)
    {
        throw Derived();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test ob; ob.fun();
}
```

Can function fun() throw exceptions of derived types when its exception specification list has base type ?

Comment: The "correct" answer would be that exception specifications are a bad idea that unfortunately made it into the standard. Real code uses only `throw()`.

Comment: When is `throw()` useful? I thought the standard advice was never to use exception specifications, even `throw()`.

Comment: @Tim: `throw()` allows optimizations, with C++0x coming out, compilers will be allowed to treat `throw()` as the new `noexcept` keyword and perform the related optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Derived` derives from `Base`, it technically *is-a* `Base`. So, yes, you can throw derived exception types if your method signature lists their base type.

But note that, as @MSalters says, there are [issues](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) with exception specifications.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is, yes it can, longer one :
**Don't use functions exception specifications. In new standard C++0x it will be deprecated.**

Why they deprecate it? Because in C++ exception specification not working like in java. If you try to throw something else , you will not get any compilation error( like in java). In runtime it will call `std::unexpected()` function, which will call unexpected handler function, which by default will terminate the program.

Comment: Exception specifications will not be removed in C++0x; _dynamic-exception-specification_ will be deprecated. There are two big differences.

Comment: @Charles Bailey in C++0x you can declare function without expection specification or with noexcept. am I wrong?

Comment: Your comment is not wrong, you can do either and you can also declare a function with a _dynamic-exception-specification_ (e.g. `throw()` or `throw(std::exception)`) as well.

Comment: @Charles Bailey  I changed "removed" to "deprecated."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. A function allows an exception of type `E` if its exception specification contains a type `T` such that a handler for a type `T` would match for an exception of type `E` (C++ standard 2003, 15.4)

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely correct. Sure it can, you can catch the exception by ref (to the base class) and re-throw it, for example.

```
//..
try
{
    ob.fun();
}
catch( Base& ex )
{
    // do something with the exception;

    // throw;  // if you want it to be re-thrown
}
```